# Why are some MS Access field properties hidden from VBA until they have been changed?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, dao

I am working on a function in an Access module to open up a set of backend databases, and modify a specific property of a specific field in a table. The property I am interested in changing is "TextFormat" which is a property belonging to Long Text, or Memo data types.

The table I am working with was created with VBA code, not through the UI.

The first part of my function loops through all of my backend databases, and all of the tables within them until it finds a table named "TestTable" and then it loops through that table looking for a field named "TestField." When it finds the field, it does one final loop to print out a list of all properties associated with that field.

After creating the table with VBA code, if I run this function, here is the resulting list of properties:

```
- Value
- Attributes
- CollatingOrder
- Type
- Name
- OrdinalPosition
- Size
- SourceField
- SourceTable
- ValidateOnSet
- DataUpdatable
- ForeignName
- DefaultValue
- ValidationRule
- ValidationText
- Required
- AllowZeroLength
- AppendOnly
- Expression
- FieldSize
- OriginalValue
- VisibleValue
- Precision
- Scale
```

As you can see, TextFormat is not in this list.

However, if I open up one of the backend databases, and manually change the Text Format property of that field, and then re-run the function, I get a new list of properties:

```
- Value
- Attributes
- CollatingOrder
- Type
- Name
- OrdinalPosition
- Size
- SourceField
- SourceTable
- ValidateOnSet
- DataUpdatable
- ForeignName
- DefaultValue
- ValidationRule
- ValidationText
- Required
- AllowZeroLength
- AppendOnly
- Expression
- FieldSize
- OriginalValue
- VisibleValue
- Precision
- Scale
- ColumnWidth
- ColumnOrder
- ColumnHidden
- IMEMode
- IMESentenceMode
- UnicodeCompression
- TextFormat
- TextAlign
- AggregateType
- ResultType
- CurrencyLCID
```

It is only at this point that I am able to access the "TextFormat" property with VBA code.

I would like to avoid opening up all of my backend databases (50+) just to update this property. If anyone has an explanation as to why these properties are hidden from VBA until I change them manually, any help is appreciated!

Here is the looping part of the code to generate the list of properties:

```vb
For Each tdfLoop In db.TableDefs
    If tdfLoop.Name = "TestTable" Then
        For Each prp In tdfLoop.Fields("TestField").Properties
            Debug.Print prp.Name
        Next prp
    End If
Next tdfLoop
```

I was expecting to get a list of ALL properties for "TestField," but they don't show up until I manually change one of the hidden properties in the UI of the backend database.

Comment: That's by design. Such properties are rarely used, so list the default setting for a property if it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA [Field.CreateProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field-createproperty-method-dao) to create the missing property and give it a value.  Here's a brief example with a memo field in my database.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim prp As DAO.Property
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("MyTable")
Set fld = tdf.Fields("memo_field")
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("TextFormat", dbByte, 0) ' 0 = plain text
                                                      ' 1 = rich text
fld.Properties.Append prp
```

Hopefully adapting your code to use that method will let you do what you need.  However, I can't explain why your memo field's *TextFormat* property is present when you create the table via the Access UI (in table Design View), but not if you create the table programmatically (as with `CREATE TABLE`). Yet I found the same outcomes with my tests.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried using the Field.CreateProperty method but it seems I may have had the wrong syntax in my first go at it. I will give this a shot tomorrow using dbByte as the property type, and I'll see if I'm able to change the TextFormat property via code. Thanks again!